# Number of responses does not match number on the Banner

Tags: bug, comments

I am have noticed that the number of comments on the banner does not match. If it is only 1 comment, that displays just fine, but if it is 2 comments, it might say 3. But around 5 comments, It might say 7 or 8. Also, As you guys comment on this, I can take screenshots and add them to this. Is this because it is using permutations? That would explain the 1,3,6 pattern.
But even still, it is not consistent.

This is what I mean:
[image: Img]

Comment: Which banner? Which comments? Do you mean the _"X new comments"_ banner? That number usually doesn't accurately reflect the actual comment count, because deletions aren't subtracted. If someone dupehammers a question, a comment exists for a very short time, causing anyone viewing that question to see a _"1 new comment[s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)"_ banner, while after refreshing, no such comment is to be found.

Comment: Can't you just add a screenshot of an existing question with those issues? Also your browser information might be helpful (have you tried another browser?)

Comment: I have access to only one browser: chrome. @SebastianProske

Comment: Mind that the notifier says the actual amount of comments, but the listed comments, when you click on the icon, are grouped by the post. If you get two comments under one question, then you'll get notified about these two, but get just one list entry for the post these comments were written to.

Comment: Yes that "X  new comments banner" @CodeCaster

Comment: See my edit. Only two higlighted comments yet a four on the inbox. @CodeCaster

Comment: About your edit: Like I said, that list shows one item per post, regardless on how many comments you got on one post. You got 3 comments and one answer (hence the 4), but there are only 2 posts. That's why it shows you two new entries.

Comment: So it grouped the comments on the post into 1, and the answer on the post into another 1? @Tom

Comment: Correct. If you would write a comment under the answer and someone would reply to you under the answer, then you would get notified about 5 events, but still get only two items listed. A second answer post would then cause a third item to be listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

[image]

Is a summary: you have one answer and three comments, totaling four notifications. Events on the same post with the same category are grouped in one line in your inbox.